# How to set AbsoluteLayout positions and dimensions dynamically on Android MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, layout, maui

I am experimenting with AbsoluteLayout and have set up a very basic page, which consists of one grid with 2 rows.

The first row holds another grid, which contains a button, and the second row contains an AbsoluteLayout laying out 2 BoxViews across the available height (the height of the page minus the height taken by the first row).

Each box is to share a different proportion of the page. And clicking the button changes the proportion of the page attributed to each BoxView.

Here is the code:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" RowDefinitions="auto, *">
    <Grid x:Name="topBar" HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Green" >
        <Button VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Change layout" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </Grid>
    
    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1" x:Name="absoluteLayout">
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" x:Name="blueBox"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="redBox"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Grid>
```

```cs
Rect _blueRect;
Rect _redRect;
    
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    
    double availableHeight = height - topBar.Height;
    
    _blueRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, availableHeight * 0.7);
    
    _redRect = new Rect(0, _blueRect.Height, width, availableHeight * 0.3);
    
    absoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(blueBox, _blueRect);
    absoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(redBox, _redRect);
}
    
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double availableHeight = Height - topBar.Height;
    
    _blueRect = new Rect(0, 0, Width, availableHeight * 0.4);
    
    _redRect = new Rect(0, _blueRect.Height, Width, availableHeight * 0.6);
    
    absoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(blueBox, _blueRect);
    absoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(redBox, _redRect);
}
```

Now this code will work perfectly fine on Windows, but not on Android. The layout changes requested in OnSizeAllocated are never taken into account, and I have tried some basic things like calling InvalidateMeasure or ForceLayout, without success.

I suspect this might be a bug and maybe I am missing a simple workaround, or could take a slightly different approach to implement the scenario described here? Thanks a lot for any input on this.

Comment: Could it be that it also needs LayoutFlags?

Comment: @FreakyAli unfortunately no, LayoutFlags are solely for relative sizing/positioning if I read the docs correctly, the expected behavior with the provided code is to interpret the Rect values as absolute coordinates and dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced the issue. I found the problem was
between the layout changes and child resizing.

You can add the two lines code below at the beginning of the Button_Clicked。

```
var blueLayoutBounds = absoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(blueBox);
var redLayoutBounds = absoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(redBox);
```

And then you will see the value is correct. The layout changes requested in OnSizeAllocated is successful.

But if you use the `var blueHeight = blueBox.Height`, you will find the value is **0**. So it seems the layout changes didn't notify the **BoxView** to resize. You can report this on the [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui).

And for a workaround, you can set the **HeightRequest** for the **BoxView** manually:

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    
    double availableHeight = height - topBar.Height;
    
    _blueRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, availableHeight * 0.7);
    
    _redRect = new Rect(0, _blueRect.Height, width, availableHeight * 0.3);
    
    absoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(blueBox, _blueRect);
    absoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(redBox, _redRect);
    blueBox.HeightRequest = availableHeight * 0.7;
    redBox.HeightRequest = availableHeight * 0.3;
}
    
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double availableHeight = Height - topBar.Height;
    
    _blueRect = new Rect(0, 0, Width, availableHeight * 0.4);
    
    _redRect = new Rect(0, _blueRect.Height, Width, availableHeight * 0.6);
    
    absoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(blueBox, _blueRect);
    absoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(redBox, _redRect);
    blueBox.HeightRequest = availableHeight * 0.4;
    redBox.HeightRequest = availableHeight * 0.6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will use this workaround. I had reported the issue in the meantime https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20845